# search through dataframe with a set window size and test condition

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to loop through about 15,000 files each having ~16,000 lines. Each file has 3 columns. I want to check, 3 lines at a time, if some condition is met. If it is, I want to then write out part of the file (shown below).

The condition I want to meet is, if column 3 has a value of 30 or more in all 3 lines, then print out: the name (column1), the **first** and **last** value of column 2, and the values from column 3. It should then search the next three lines in the file for the same condition. The input looks like this:

```
d3.1    1       2
d3.1    2       2
d3.1    3       2
d3.1    4       31
d3.1    5       50
d3.1    6       40
d3.1    7       13
```

The output should look like this:

```
d3.1   4   6   31   50   40
```

I've got something like this now but I'm not sure how to search through column 3, 3 lines at a time and reformat the output:

```
library(data.table)
for (i in 1:15000){
  file <- list.files('~/dir',full.names=T)
  x <- fread(file[i], header=F)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt at the guts of the functon:

```
require(data.table)
dat <- data.table(V1="d3.1",V2=1:7,V3=c(2,2,2,31,50,40,13))

dat$grp <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(dat)/3),each=3)
dat[, if(all(V3>30)) c(as.character(V1[1]),V2[1],V2[3],as.list(V3)), by=grp]

#   grp   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1:   2 d3.1  4  6 31 50 40
```

Comment: I tried your code but it fails when I increase the length of the dataframe. For example: 

require(data.table)
dat <- data.table(V1="d3.1",V2=1:14,V3=c(2,2,2,31,50,40,13,90,100,31,1,2,3,40))

dat$grp <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(dat)/3),each=ceiling(nrow(dat)/3))
dat[, if(all(V3>30)) c(as.character(V1[1]),V2[1],V2[3],as.list(V3)), by=grp]

Comment: Also, when u increase the rows of the dataframe, the grp column the commands no longer search by just 3 rows at a time.

Comment: @user3141121 - apologies, there was an error in the `dat$grp` code - it is fixed now. You will get a warning if the number of rows can not be evenly divided by 3, but that is to be expected.

Comment: I'm getting this error. Any way to get around it? Error in `[.data.table`(x.out, , if (all(V3 > 30)) c(as.character(V1[1]),  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group